# Has Facebook changed the way they read meta data?

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-graph

I have a site built on Joomla!3.2. Recently I tried to share on Facebook an article from my site and it seems that Facebook doesn't read my *meta data*.

Here is my *`<head>`* output:

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.highplay.pt/blog/porque-e-que-as-historias-vencem-uma-visao-nigel-barlow" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="High Play Institute - Porque é que as histórias vencem uma visão?" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.highplay.pt/media/k2/items/cache/48ee1e8a0a8f50dce4f8cb9ab418e211_XL.jpg" />
```

And here is my **Graph API** from Open Graph Debugger

```
{
   "id": "191441707711484",
   "url": "http://www.highplay.pt/blog/porque-e-que-as-historias-vencem-uma-visao-nigel-barlow",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "http://www.highplay.pt/blog/porque-e-que-as-historias-vencem-uma-visao-nigel-barlow",
   "updated_time": "2013-11-21T11:38:46+0000",
   "created_time": "2013-11-21T11:22:05+0000",
   "is_scraped": true
}
```

The weird in this is that I tried in last month and it looked great, with XL Image, description and Article name, I dunno why this is happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes from using gzip in my page.  When I disable gzip, Facebook is able to scrape information from my pages.

See: [Response code 200 but nothing is scraped by the Object Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417640/response-code-200-but-nothing-is-scraped-by-the-object-debugger)